# Autosubmit form with existing 'submit' element

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with 1 form on it. So to auto-submit the form I could use this:

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
```

However, there can be an element in the form with name="submit". This breaks the above code. Apart from removing or renaming the 'submit' field, is there another way to auto-submit a form?

Cheers.

Comment: you shouldn't name any form elements "submit", as you've now found out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the form an id and then use `document.getElementById('id-of-your-form').submit();`

Comment: This does not work when there is an element with name="submit" or even with id="submit" - my form id is: 'test'.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason that you'd want to keep a form element with name "submit"? Renaming that seems like it is the most pragmatic solution. Avoid name collisions when possible, and all that.

Assuming there is, give the form an ID and reference that.